# I want to cut a string after 15 characters

Tags: php

In my php file i am using

```
$html .= $prev->link_name;
```

to display the name of a listing. Unfortunately some listings have many characters so I would like to cut them after 15 characters and add three dots "..." at the end of the listing name.

I know that I have to add something like that:

```
 $string = (strlen($string) > 15) ? substr($string,0,15).'...' : $string;
```

but I don't know exactly how can I use it with:

```
$html .= $prev->link_name;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know what you need it for, but the css ellipsis property might be better suited than truncating your string in php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When in doubt, split it up:

```
$string = $prev->link_name;

if (mb_strlen($string) > 15)
  $string = mb_substr($string, 0, 15) . '...';

$html .= $string;
```

Or you can do it in a single line:

```
$html .= (mb_strlen($prev->link_name) > 15) ? mb_substr($prev->link_name, 0, 15) . '...': $prev->link_name;
```

But if it's hard for you to read such a line, it's better to spend a couple of lines to make it more readable. No shame it that: the single line version is a very long line, and hard to comprehend with all those different expressions. I would choose the multi-line version myself in this case.

-edit-

Updated to use [multibyte string functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) as per request in comments.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. It works great. Only one little problem as i am using greek characters it displays Listing example na�... How can i get rid of � ??

Comment: I think that should work with `mb_substr` instead of normal `substr`. There are multibyte (mb) versions of other functions too, for instance for strlen.: [multibyte string functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php).

Comment: @user3608836 If GokezTrol answer whas correct, than you should accept his answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
$html .= (strlen($prev->link_name) > 15) ? substr($prev->link_name,0,15).'...' : $prev->link_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check a string that will contain the name and use after checking the length of characters. For example if we have some string:

```
//Some string
$string = 'Yuriy        Ivanovich  '; //Replace with   $string = $prev->link_name;

/* 
The responses above, we would get an answer next

string 'Yuriy        Iv...' (length=18)

Not correct! Change it!
*/

//Remove extra spaces 
$string = preg_replace ('/\s+/', ' ',  $string) ;

//Check if string not empty
if(!empty($string)){
    if(mb_strlen($string) > 15)
        $string = mb_substr($string, 0, 15) . '...';
}
$html .= $string;

var_dump($html);
```

Result:

```
string 'Yuriy Ivanovich...' (length=18)
```